# modifying a list in a function when passed to another function in Python

Tags: python, list, scope, parameter-passing

Look at the code below:

```
def f1(l):
  l[0] = 'row'
  l[1] = 'col'
  return True
def f2():
  l = [0,0]
  f1(l)
  print(l)
f2()
```

running the `f2` function, prints `l = ['row', 'col']`. Why did this happen?

My Python version is 3.7.13

Comment: What do you think should have happened instead, and why?

Comment: Because you mutated the dict. What else did you expect to happen?

Comment: @ScottHunter @juanpa.arrivillaga I gueseed  `l = [0,0]` because I didn't return the list from `f1`. I think that `l ` could be `['row', 'col']` in 2 situations:
1) When I've defined `l` globally and
2) when `f1` returns a list and in `f2`, I have this line: `l = f1(l)`